# performSegueWithIdentifier doesn't show new view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, segue

I'm having an issue with my performSegueWithIdentifier, because he fires and when I get a breakpoint on the viewDidLoad of the NextViewController he enters and executes fine. Problem is there is no output and the screen continues to show the CurrentViewController. What can be the error ?

(CurrentViewController is a TableViewController)

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selected = [self.evlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"eventlist" sender:self];
    return indexPath;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NSString * event_id = [_selected objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * event_name = [_selected objectForKey:@"label"];
    [segue.destinationViewController setEvent_id:event_id];
        [segue.destinationViewController setEvent_id:event_id];
        [segue.destinationViewController setEvent_name:event_name];
}
```

(NextViewController is a ViewController)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _evname_label.text = _event_name;
    _evid_label.text = _event_id;
    NSLog(@"This is strange %@",_event_name);

}
```

He logs everything as expected... the view doesn't show!

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in prepareForSegue? If it doesn't reach it post a screenshot of the relevant part of your storyboard. If it does reach it check the name of the segue within prepareForSegue is eventList

Comment: he reaches that breakpoint and even passes the arguments correctly.. guess i would have to delete and start over xD

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears correct. Are you sure the segue is configured correctly? Check the `Style`, `Presentation` and `Transition` styles.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I had a bug in my coding... I was calling the prepareforsegue inside a for cycle and the problem was somewhere around it.
Prepareforsegue outside for and it was cool :) Thanks all